# Merging two branches on Github

Tags: github, merge

I'm new to Github and I have a branch that I want to merge with the master. I couldn't merge it via git command line, its very complicated.
I tried to merge it on Github site following below documentation:

[Merging a pull request on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/)

But I got the following message:

> There isn’t anything to compare!

Here's the project:

https://github.com/SumayahAlharbi/erecords

***What does 4 commits behind master mean?***
[image]

**Update**

Please check below pictures:

***I thought I did the merging successfully but nothing changes!***
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the difference between the master and your branch. Run this command from your local branch : `git diff --name-only master_branch`

Comment: @NicholasK Sir I got 'bash: git: command not found' I don't know how to use git

Comment: What is the name of your branch?

Comment: its ExportFeature developed by another contributor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked your repo. The changes of `ExportFeature` branch are already merged into the `master` branch, and then the merge is reverted. That's why now if you raise a pull request to merge `ExportFeature` into `master`, you would get `There isn’t anything to compare!`.

See the latest commits on `ExportFeature` which are already present in the `master` branch.

[image]

[image]

The reason you are seeing `4 commits behind master` on `ExportFeature` branch is since the `master` branch has 4 more commits than the `ExportFeature` branch. If you see the total commits on `ExportFeature` branch, it's 7, whereas the total number of commits on the `master` branch is 11. If you need to do any more changes on the `ExportFeature` branch, you would need to get the latest changes from the `master` branch by running the command `git pull origin master` when your current branch is `ExportFeature` on your local git terminal.

Comment: I think a `git pull --rebase origin master` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Can you check my update please, how to make sure that the merging is done successfully while everything is 2 days ago !

Comment: The problem is that you have reverted the merge of `ExportFeature` branch on your master, which has taken away the changes of `ExportFeature` from master. Hence you will not be able to merge the changes from `ExportFeature` now to master.

Comment: @Learner I guess you'll have to go to the previous commit before the merging of the ExportFeature branch and then open a pull request to merge from ExportFeature to master.

Comment: @NicholasK that depends, rebase may or may not be needed.

Answer (score 4):

**What does 4 commits behind master mean?**

- It means that the master branch has 4 commits which are not present in your branch currently. You need to rebase your branch and then create a **New Pull
  Request** which will be needed to be reviewed and finally approved so
  that your branch can be merged with the master.

**There isn’t anything to compare!**

- Check the difference between the master and your branch. Click the *Compare* icon in Git hub or run this
  command from your local branch in Git Bash : `git diff --name-only master_branch`.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.